# onClick event - Run a javascript AFTER previous one has finished in the same onClick event

Tags: javascript, php

Code looks like this (My PHP server generates this line replacing the %% variables):

```
<button type="submit" id="buttons" name="add_to_inv" onclick="ServInfo('inv_items','/magagest/index.php','req=add_item&item=%icode% - %idesc%&iqty=%iqty%&iprice=%iprice%&itnum='+trCount('inv_items',false),'','y');ShowFieldTotal('inv_items','iprice','sub-total',2);">+</button>;
```

I want THIS

```
ShowFieldTotal('inv_items','iprice','sub-total',2);
```

to run ONLY when the elements of the first script have been added on my webpage. Basically, it adds an item line in a table and, what I actually want it to do that I can't do, calculate the total of each items once their lines have been added to the table from the first script:

```
ServInfo('inv_items','/magagest/index.php','req=add_item&item=%icode% - %idesc%&iqty=%iqty%&iprice=%iprice%&itnum='+trCount('inv_items',false),'','y')
```

Comment: You should add an extra parameter to ServInfo so you can pass in ShowFieldTotal. Then call that function when ServInfo is finished. JQuery does this for most / all of its functions

Comment: seems like a job for `onLoad`  "ONLY when the elements of the first script have been added on my webpage"  | https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onload.asp

Answer (score 0):

Modify your ServInfo function like this.

```
function ServInfo (args...) {
    --- your code ---
    ....
    ....

    //call ShowFieldTotal when ServInfo() is finished.
    ShowFieldTotal(args...);
}
```

Comment: I cannot do that as ServInfo is there ONLY to retrieve data from the server side and bring it to client side using AJAX. Where the terme Serve Information (ServInfo). The code ShowFieldTotal is ALSO in a different js file than my AJAX call.

Answer (score 0):

You can make another function which calls the two functions one after another and bind that function to the onclick event.

Answer (score 0):

ControlAltDel's answer makes it simple and easy. I actually added another parameter to my ServInfo which catches a string which it converts to code. Basically, I called the "eval" function to parse the code written in a string I pass to ServInfo. My new onClick event looks like this:

```
<button type="submit" id="buttons" name="add_to_inv" onclick="ServInfo('inv_items','/magagest/index.php','req=add_item&item=%icode% - %idesc%&iqty=%iqty%&iprice=%iprice%&itnum='+trCount('inv_items',false),'','y','ShowFieldTotal(\'inv_items\',\'iprice\',\'sub-total\',2)');">+</button>
```

I added the following to my ServInfo code:

```
// Execute a string if a user defined one
        if (exec_string != "") {
            eval(exec_string);
        }
```

For the curious, My ServInfo function now looks like this:

```
// AJAX simple HTTP GET request
function ServInfo(pop_field_id,web_page,params="",form_id="",append_data_to_output = "",exec_string = "") {

var sparams = params;
var swpage = web_page;
var eobj = document.getElementById(pop_field_id);

// Get form field values if a form id is specified
if (form_id != "") {
    var efrm = document.getElementById(form_id);
    sparams += "&"+GetDivFields(form_id);
}

// If HTML element to populate does not exist, exit
if (typeof(eobj) == "!undefined" || eobj == null)   {return;}

if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    // IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else {
    // IE6-
    xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        if (append_data_to_output == "y") {
            document.getElementById(pop_field_id).innerHTML += this.responseText;
        }
        if (append_data_to_output == "") {
            document.getElementById(pop_field_id).innerHTML = this.responseText;
        }
        // Execute a string if a user defined one
        if (exec_string != "") {
            eval(exec_string);
        }
    }
};
// Add the question mark if there is any parameters to pass
if (sparams != "") {swpage += "?";}

xmlhttp.open("GET",swpage+sparams,true);
xmlhttp.send();

}
```